# JSTL - getting an object from java

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I'm trying to print all the elements from a table in a database using a JSP for an assignment, but the requirement is to get the elements from the backend. (JSP CRUD operations work just fine). The problem is that I get an empty table. Here is my code:

JSP:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>SELECT Operation</title>
</head>

<body>

<c:set var="students" scope="session" value="${StudentDaoImpl.allStudents}"/>

<table border="1" width="100%">
<tr>
   <th>Student ID</th>
   <th>Name</th>
</tr>

<c:forEach var="student" items="${students}">
<tr>
   <td><c:out value="${student.ID}"/></td>
   <td><c:out value="${student.Name}"/></td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

StudentDaoImpl class:

```
    public class StudentDaoImpl implements StudentDao{

    private Connection connection;

    public StudentDaoImpl(){
        Properties connectionProps = new Properties();
        connectionProps.put("user", "root");
        connectionProps.put("password", "password");

        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test",connectionProps);
            System.out.println("Connection to MySql successful.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Could not connect to MySql.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public List<Student> getAllStudents(){
        StudentDaoImpl DAO = new StudentDaoImpl();
        return DAO.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM students");
    }


    private List<Student> executeQuery(String sqlQuery){
        List<Student> students = new LinkedList<>();

        try {
            Statement statement = this.connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sqlQuery);
            while(resultSet.next()){
                Student currentStudent = new Student();
                currentStudent.setID(resultSet.getInt("ID"));
                currentStudent.setName(resultSet.getString("NAME"));
                students.add(currentStudent);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return students;
    }

}
```

And the Student class:

```
public class Student {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public Student(){

    }

    public void setID(int newID){
        this.id = newID;
    }

    public int getID(){
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setName(String newName){
        this.name = newName;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }

}
```

If I just access the database directly from the JSP, everything is a-ok, but if I try it this way, all I get is the table header.

Also, the StudentDaoImpl class works fine using just java and printing the results to the standard output, so for sure this is a communication problem.

I am using Netbeans. I also get this runtime:

```
Running war on http://localhost:8080/JSPwithJDBC
Using existing Tomcat server configuration at D:\NetBeans 8.0.2\Projects\JSPwithJDBC\target\tomcat
Feb 08, 2015 3:16:13 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Embedded start
INFO: Starting tomcat server
Feb 08, 2015 3:16:13 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.29
Feb 08, 2015 3:16:14 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Feb 08, 2015 3:16:14 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
```

It seems it's running tomcat 6, even though I have tomcat 8 installed. I've read that tomcat 6 is problematic with this... Is there any way I can force it to run on tomcat 8?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to your question is in your log snippet. If you look closely, you will see that it says it is starting the existing tomcat instance which is associated with netbeans.

```
"Using existing Tomcat server configuration at D:\NetBeans 8.0.2\Projects\JSPwithJDBC\target\tomcat"
```

If you really want to start your Tomcat 8 installation from Netbeans. First install the Tomcat 8 server instance with Netbens.

Follow the instructions in the below link. It has instructions for installing the tomcat 7 instance with Netbeans.

https://technology.amis.nl/2012/01/02/installing-tomcat-7-and-configuring-as-server-in-netbeans/

To answer your JSTL related question, please update your question with the request handlers data binding code.(Controller or request handler mapping class code)